# align macro kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operators, bitwise-operators

I am unable to understand what this macro does. These are defined in `linux-kernel` but my doubt is independent of that. I am unable to understand what does `(((x)+(mask))&~(mask))` line does.

```
#define ALIGN(x,a)              __ALIGN_MASK(x,(typeof(x))(a)-1)
#define __ALIGN_MASK(x,mask)    (((x)+(mask))&~(mask))
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Say you have a number: `0x1006`

For some reasons you want to align it to a `4` bytes boundary.

With a 4-byte boundary, you know aligned values are `0x1000`, `0x1004`, `0x1008`, etc.
You then also know the aligned value of `0x1006` is `0x1008`.

How would you get `0x1008`? The alignment mask for alignment value `4` is `(4 - 1) = 0x03`

Now `0x1006 + 0x03 = 0x1009` and `0x1009 & ~0x03 = 0x1008`

This operation is the  `__ALIGN_MASK` macro.

If you want to pass the value `4` (the alignment) instead of directly `0x03` (the alignment mask), you have the `ALIGN` macro

Comment: A very succinct explanation that is easy to follow.

Answer (score 11):

```
#define ALIGN(x,a)              __ALIGN_MASK(x,(typeof(x))(a)-1)
```

the alignment, `a`, is cast to `x`'s type, and then one is subtracted. The alignment should be a power of 2, so that results in a number of the bit-pattern `00..011..11` of `x`'s type, the mask (`k` 1s if `a = 2^k`).

Then

```
#define __ALIGN_MASK(x,mask)    (((x)+(mask))&~(mask))
```

adds the value of the mask to `x`, so that `(x)+ (mask)` is at least as large as the smallest multiple of the alignment that is not smaller than `x` and smaller than the next larger multiple. Then the bitwise and with the complement of the mask reduces that number to that multiple of the alignment.

For masks of the form `2^k - 1`, the computation

```
(x + mask) & ~mask
```

is the same as

```
(x + 2^k - 1) - ((x + 2^k - 1) % (2^k))
```

or

```
((x + 2^k - 1)/(2^k)) * (2^k)
```

Comment: Will this trick work for `alignment` which are not power of 2.

Comment: No, it works only for powers of 2. But specifying alignment is only useful for powers of 2, so no useful cases are mishandled.